# Can not show Toast with Galio-Framework

Tags: react-native, toast

I'm init a test app whith expo-cli.
Install galio-framework
And put one of Toast in screens.But not show anything.
Is my code wrong?
this is my code in App.js

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button } from 'react-native';
import {Toast,Block} from 'galio-framework';

export default function App() {
  let isShow= true;
  const { useNativeDriver } = this.props;
  // const [isShow, setShow] = useState(false);
  const setShow = (v)=>{
    console.log("show change "+v);
    isShow= v;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Button shadowless onPress={() => setShow(!isShow)} style={styles.btnCC}>click here for toast notifications</Button>
      <Block style={styles.bl}>
        <Toast isShow={true} positionIndicator="top">This is a top positioned toast</Toast>
        <Toast isShow={isShow} positionIndicator="center" color="success">This is a center positioned toast</Toast>
      </Block>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  bl:{
    flex: 1,
    height:200,
    width:100,
    // alignItems: 'center',
    // justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  btnCC:{
    width:200,
    backgroundColor: '#006600',
  }
});
```

Is my code wrong?Or is the framework bug?

Comment: you did not add your code here

Comment: @TBA  I just edited it wrong, now it's ok

Answer (score 1):

`isShow` variable must be React state. Change code like this

```js
export default function App() {
  const [isShow, setShow] = React.useState(false)
  const { useNativeDriver } = this.props;


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Button shadowless onPress={() => setShow(!isShow)} style={styles.btnCC}>click here for toast notifications</Button>
      <Block style={styles.bl}>
        <Toast isShow={true} positionIndicator="top">This is a top positioned toast</Toast>
        <Toast isShow={isShow} positionIndicator="center" color="success">This is a center positioned toast</Toast>
      </Block>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I've abandoned this framework in favor of NativeBase

Comment: anyway ,thank you